# set "run as administrator" flag programmatically

Tags: api, installshield, uac

Is it possible to programmatically set the "Run As Administrator" flag on exe file or shortcut file?

Does Installshield support this functionality if i'll do it as part of the installation process?

I'm trying to find the relevant command line / API / installshield command for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upstream build process should be manifesting your EXE with the require administrator attribute.   This doesn't have anything to do with InstallShield or the shortcut.  Done correctly when the user clicks the shortcut,  Windows will see the manifest and UAC will prompt for elevation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
I'm using Visual Studio 2003 and did not find way to build the application this method. is it possible to perform the menifesting process in VS 2003?

Comment: What's your project type?  C++, VB.NET, C#?

Comment: C++ Console Application (Not Managed)

Comment: For VS 2003, read:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx