# How can you install a shortcut with the 'Run As Admin' option automatically toggled on?

Tags: windows-installer, admin

I have an application which needs to be run as admin for all of the features to work correctly.  I would like to be able to install the app and create shortcuts with that option automatically toggled on.  Is this possible?  I'm using InstallAware 9 to create my installation.

Thanks,
brian

Comment: possible duplicate of [set "run as administrator" flag programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405098/set-run-as-administrator-flag-programmatically)

Comment: yep you are right... whats the process for amending this?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, an application manifest that specifies administrator access will cause this to happen on all OSes where this is an issue.

Here's the relevant fragment.

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

Comment: I tried this and rather getting the UAC popup, i got one which stated the following: "The requested operation requires elevation."  There is only an OK button.  The app does not launch.  Is this expected?

Comment: what OS are you using?  UAC has different manifestations & management oiptions depending on the specific Windows version. The article at technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_S2 talks about configuration options for Vista & Server 2008.

Comment: Manifesting a random .exe on my XP SP3 machine brings up a credentials prompt. Maybe your UAC aready has some of the prompt control options already set.