# Run shortcut as administrator

Tags: installshield

In InstallShield 2015 Premier , how to set a shortcut created for an EXE to have ability of Run As Administrator. I have searched every corner in InstallShield, but not find option I need

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set "run as administrator" flag programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405098/set-run-as-administrator-flag-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no front-end option. However, you can create a registry entry in your project to set up the following:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\yourapp.EXE"="~ RUNASADMIN"
It may or may not accept [INSTALLDIR] variable, if it does not, you can create registry entry using InstallScript. 
Alternatively, you can [embed application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest?view=vs-2019) into your application itself, in which case you won't need to worry about setting admin rights in IS.